# Full outer join misbehaving

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in the same sql-server database that store application names and usernames (among other things) from two consecutive quarters. What I want is a full join that shows users in table A that are not in table B and vis versa.

**EDIT:** Both table_a and table_b contain two or more records where AppName and Username have identical values, making the DISTINCT necessary. I've edited the examples below to reflect this.

table_a:

```
-----------------------
| AppName  | Username |
-----------------------
| app1     | jdoe     |
| app1     | jsmith   |
| app1     | jdoe     |
| app2     | jsmith   |
-----------------------
```

table_b:

```
-----------------------
| AppName  | Username |
-----------------------
| app1     | fbar     |
| app1     | jsmith   |
| app1     | jboehner |
| app1     | fbar     |
| app3     | jboehner |
-----------------------
```

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.username as q2, b.username as q3
FROM tablea as a
FULL JOIN tableb as b
ON a.username = b.username
WHERE a.appname = 'app1'
AND b.appname = 'app1'
```

Expected result:

```
-----------------------
| q2       | q3       |
-----------------------
| jdoe     |          |
| jsmith   | jsmith   |
|          | fbar     |
-----------------------
|          | jboehner |
-----------------------
```

Actual result:

```
-----------------------
| q2       | q3       |
-----------------------
| jsmith   | jsmith   |
-----------------------
```

What gives??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a WHERE clause on an OUTER JOINed table (in this case both of your tables) changes it to an INNER JOIN since the filter is applied to the result of the join and *all* conditions must be met. In your case this is not possible except on rows that match (it forces it to an INNER JOIN). I suspect this is what you meant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.username as q2, b.username as q3
FROM dbo.tablea as a
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tableb as b
ON a.username = b.username
AND (a.appname = b.appname)
WHERE a.appname = 'app1' OR b.appname = 'app1';

-- or

SELECT DISTINCT a.username as q2, b.username as q3
FROM dbo.tablea as a
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tableb as b
ON a.username = b.username
AND (a.appname = b.appname)
WHERE 'app1' IN (a.appname, b.appname);
```

Comment: Couldn't you do the FULL OUTER JOIN on a.username = b.username AND a.appname = b.appname and then put the WHERE criteria after the fact since you've already created the dataset with the NULLs in the appropriate places?

Comment: Will SQL Server be able to push the filter into the individual tables this way? I'm used to manually pushing the filters down into derived tables.

Comment: @Love2Learn yes, but the important part is that the WHERE clause can't have an AND to both tables (this makes it an INNER JOIN).

Comment: In the case of a full join, won't having a where clause on either table result in either an inner join, or a left outer join?  Just add the where criteria to the on clause.

Comment: @Andrew if you just move the WHERE clause to the ON, you will also get unmatched rows for other apps other than app1 - the filter doesn't apply.

Answer (score -3):

The where should simply be or not and:
WHERE a.appname = 'app1' OR b.appname = 'app1'

Comment: No, this will allow either table to introduce rows where `appname <> 'app1'`.